# Export DataTables to PDF is repeating the header

Tags: pdf, datatables

I am using the function to export PDF from jquery DataTables. It works but it repeats the header like the image below:

[image]

Does anyone know of any way to export not repeating the header?

```js
$("#table").DataTable({
    buttons: [
      {
      text: '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF',
      extend: 'pdf',
      className: 'btn btn-danger',
      orientation: 'landscape',
      title: 'My table to PDF',
      pageSize: 'A3',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
        }
      }
  ],  
  responsive    : true,
  paging        : true,
  searching     : true
});
```

Comment: I guess you have some issues with your markup, perhaps trying to have two `<tr>` sections in your `<thead>`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but the markup is correct, I have only one <tr> within <thear>, the header repetition occurs at the beginning of each new page, however, I would need only one header on the first page and the rest only data

Comment: Now I see what you mean!! Interesting issue, I do not think this have been asked before, ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not so well documented, but after googling around in the [**pdfmake**](http://pdfmake.org) universe I realized there is a `headerRows` attribute that defines how many pages the header should be repeated on. This can be manipulated through DataTables' `customize(doc)` callback :

```js
buttons: [{
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  customize: function(doc) {
    doc.content[1].table.headerRows = 0
  }
}]
```

This will prevent the headers from being repeated, i.e only be included on the first page "0".

Demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/mzaudL7c/**

**Note**: The structure of `doc.content` can vary depending on your setup. So if it not work for you 1:1, investigate `doc` to find the correct index.